# Confusion in use of port number and http

Tags: http

When we make a request a page from a server, the request by default goes to port 80 on the server that is the http server. Why do we then type http before the path of a resource. If the request is going to a http server it must be a http request.

Comment: Think about it:  can you run both an FTP service and an HTTP service on the same server?  Yes.  Can a browser speak to multiple protocols?  Also yes.  Therefore, we need to specify which protocol to use, and the prefix of the URL identifies that.

Comment: This is off topic here. This is a basic networking question. You make several assumptions that you have not examined, including that a http server only does one thing, and that http is always port 80. Server != Service. Services respond to ports. Servers run Services.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got that the other way round. *If* you type `http://`, *then* the request goes to port 80 unless overridden (e.g. `http://www.yourserver.blah:8080/...`).

But if for example you typed `https://...`, then the request would go - again, unless overridden - to port 443/tcp and would even "speak" a different "dialect". The same goes for `ftp://` and port 21, *if* the browser understands the FTP protocol (as most do).

Most browsers do consider the lack of a `http://` qualifier in a Web address as meaning "this goes to HTTP port `80/tcp`", and they automatically add the `http://` for you. Otherwise, you have to specify, and the port chosen will follow the specification.

Answer (score 2):

To better understand how a URI (URL) works, you should refer to the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

> ```
> The generic URI syntax consists of a hierarchical sequence of
>    components referred to as the scheme, authority, path, query, and
>    fragment.
>
> The following are two example URIs and their component parts:
>
>          foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
>          \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
>           |           |            |            |        |
>        scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
>           |   _____________________|__
>          / \ /                        \
>          urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
> ```

It is also useful not to think of the "server" as a box, but as "service" running on a specific port. When the client makes the request, it doesn't know who will be receiving it. While the standard is 80, there is no reason that cannot be an SSH server. Imagine a scenario where someone is behind a firewall and wants to SSH to their home box, if they run the SSH server on port 80, they may be able to get past basic firewall rules that allow you to open a connection to port 80. There are defaults, but they are not requirements.

Also keep in mind, that the usage of a URL is for the user. When you specify `http://` it tells the user to create an HTTP request to the address. Your request of the browser for *http://www.example.com* is then translated to the HTTP protocol. [This article](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/http_basics.html) gives a pretty good description:

> For example, the browser translated the URL
> http://www.test101.com/doc/index.html into the following request
> message:
>
> ```
> GET /docs/index.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.test101.com
> Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, */*
> Accept-Language: en-us
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
> (blank line)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the browser what protocol you want it to speak to the server. Most browsers support multiple protocols in the main navigation area, such as https and ftp, which use port 443 and 21/22 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has mentioned it so far, it is not required to specify `http://` or `https://`

Example: Google recommends using just `//` instead of `http://` or `https://` as it will default to whatever is being used on the page.

Example from [Google code](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```